# Работа с хранимой процедурой с помощью C#. Несколько Select

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, ado.net

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Check_of_condition_airplane]
@id_airplane int
AS
BEGIN
SELECT Исправность FROM dbo.Список_самолетов WHERE ID_Самолета = @id_airplane;

SELECT a.name_detail, b.detail_order, b.repair_need
FROM dbo.Details_for_specific_airplane(@id_airplane) as a
JOIN
dbo.List_of_details_order(@id_airplane) as b
ON (a.id_detail = b.id_detail)
END
```

Вот код самой процедуры. Как видно, в ней имеется два Select. Я хотел бы в своей программе реализовать вывод обех результатов Select в разные DataGridView. Я пытался сделать через SqlDataReader и его метод NextResult. Так же пытался и через SqlDataAdapter. Но, к сожалению, обе попытки не получились. Первый результирующий набор я получаю, а вот со вторым беда, ни разу не получилось его достать.
Вот мой код на C#:

```
private void ResultButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=airplanes;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("EXECUTE dbo.Check_of_condition_airplane 3",con);
        SqlDataReader a = command.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable TempTable = new DataTable();
        TempTable.Load(a);
        a.NextResult();
        DataTable TempTable1 = new DataTable();
        TempTable1.Load(a);
        Result1.DataSource = TempTable;
        Result2.DataSource = TempTable1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Дело в том, что работа с SqlServer из c# возможна огромным количеством способов. От лаконичных, но требующих дополнительных знаний, либо длинных, но прямолинейных. Чтобы отвечающим не нужно было мучиться, решая ВСЮ задачу за вас, приведите свой код, а люди подскажут, где ошибка, и куда стоит копать

Comment: @pkuderov, спасибо, сейчас напишу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратимся к [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D5%F0%E0%ED%E8%EC%E0%FF_%EF%F0%EE%F6%E5%E4%F3%F0%E0): Хранимые процедуры могут возвращать множества результатов, то есть результаты запроса SELECT.
То есть возвращается только один набор SELECT. Это не значит, что нельзя усложнить себе жизнь и добиться возвращения двух и более наборов данных. Здесь, мне думается, могут помочь возвращаемые параметры. Что-то в этом роде:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Check_of_condition_airplane]
@id_airplane int,
@myTable TABLE OUTPUT
```

А потом в коде процедуры присвоить этой переменной нужное значение. (не уверен, что в таком виде оно сработает, но можно в эту сторону покопать...)

По моему мнению, Вы без надобности усложнили задачу. Сделайте две хранимки и выбирайте их по-очереди.

**UPD:** был не прав. Нашел такой способ работы с несколькими таблицами:

```
var cmd = this.GetNewStoreProc(storeProc, storeProcParams);
var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
var dataContainer = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dataContainer);
```

Дальше выбираем таблицы по-очереди. Что-то вроде этого:

```
 var dt0 = dataContainer.Tables[0];
 var dt1 = dataContainer.Tables[1];
```

Comment: Неправда. Может быть сколько угодно select'ов и все они доступны из вызывающего кода.

Comment: Спасибо, но @Qwertiy был прав, если я вас правильно понял.Мой запрос t-sql возвращает мне результаты для обеих Select.